# I want to make a loading feature on page using php and jquery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, jquery-ui

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $('img').show();
            });
        </script>
        <script>
            $(window).load(function(){
                $('img').hide();
            });
        </script>
<body>
    <img src="loading.gif" id="imgId" />
    <form method="GET" >
        <input type="submit" name="btn_test" value="Click me">
        <input type="submit" name="btn_test2" value="Click me no action">
    </form>
    <?php
        if(isset($_GET['btn_test']))
        {
            for($i=0;$i<=100000;$i++)
            {
                echo $i;
                echo "<br>";
                echo "T";
                echo "<br>";
                echo "H";
                echo "<br>";
                echo "A";
                echo "<br>";
                echo "N";
                echo "<br>";
                echo "K";
                echo "<br>";
                echo "S";
                echo "<br>";
                echo "<p>";
            }

        }

        if(isset($_GET['btn_test2']))
        {
            echo "No action....";
        }   
    ?>

    </body>

</html>
```

This code is working, but loading image appears on the top. But is there any way to load this image on a dialog and page can not be clickable that time?(so that user can't do anything that time)

Thanks in advance for reading.

Comment: Just curious... Why are you outputting "THANKS" on separate lines 100000 times?

Comment: It's a sample code, actual code is fetching data from mysql and operation takes to fetch around 82 seconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add some `CSS` styling to an element that will house your loading image.

For example, change the code for your loading image to:

```
<div id="loader">
    <img src="loading.gif" id="imgId" />
</div>
```

Then in `CSS`:

```
#loader {
  position: absolute;             /* relative to the body */
  z-index: 9999;                  /* over all other elements */
  height: 100%;                   /* full body height */
  width: 100%;                    /* full body width */
  top: 0;                         /* distance from the top */
  left: 0;                        /* distance from the left */
  right: 0;                       /* distance from the right */
  bottom: 0;                      /* distance from the bottom */
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6); /* give it a background with low opacity */
}

img#imgId {
  position: absolute;             /* relative to the loading div */
  left: 50%;                      /* distance from the left */
  top: 50%;                       /* distance from the top */
}
```

Then in the JavaScript:

```
$(window).ready(function(){
    $('#loader').hide();
});
```

Comment: You just make the image on middle, but buttons and page are still clickable. So user can click the same button again and again before complete execution. Think about it.

Comment: That's the point of the `#loader` element... It's above all the other page elements so they aren't clickable and aren't as visible.

Comment: Yes, approach is really good, you are using a div rather than a ui dialog. But still dialog could have better for looking actually.